# Show 2 integrals are equal

Tags: probability, integration

I have two i.i.d continues random variables $X_0, X_1$, with PDF $f$, where the support $\subset$ $[0,\infty)$.

I need to calculate $P(X_0 \geq X_1)$. I know the answer is $\frac{1}{2}$ due to symmetry. However, I want to directly prove it using integrals.

My try:

We know that $f(x,y) = f(x)f(y)$.
So need to show:

$\int_{0}^{\infty} \int_{0}^{x_0}f(x_1)f(x_0)\,dx_1\,dx_0 = \frac{1}{2}$

Since $f(x,y) = f(x)f(y)$ is a PDF we have:

$1 = \int_{0}^{\infty} \int_{0}^{\infty}f(x_1)f(x_0) \,dx_1\,dx_0 = \int_{0}^{\infty} \int_{0}^{x_0}f(x_1)f(x_0) \,dx_1\,dx_0 + \int_{0}^{\infty} \int_{x_0}^{\infty}f(x_1)f(x_0) \,dx_1\,dx_0 $

So it is enough to show that:
$\int_{0}^{\infty} \int_{0}^{x_0}f(x_1)f(x_0) \,dx_1\,dx_0 = \int_{0}^{\infty} \int_{x_0}^{\infty}f(x_1)f(x_0) \,dx_1\,dx_0 $

To conclude. I tried manipulating the integral, but I wasn't able to show it. I think I need to use Fubini, but I am not sure.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The assumption that $\mathbb P(X_0\geqslant 0)=1$ is not necessary. Using integration by parts we can show that
\begin{align}
\mathbb P(X_0\geqslant X_1) &= \int_{-\infty}^\infty \int_{-\infty}^{x_0} f(x_1)f(x_0)\ \mathsf dx_1\ \mathsf dx_0\\
&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty F(x_0) f(x_0)\ \mathsf dx_0\\
&= \left[F(x_0)^2 \right]_{-\infty}^\infty - \int_{-\infty}^\infty F(x_0)f(x_0)\ \mathsf dx_0\\
&= 1 - \int_{-\infty}^\infty F(x_0) f(x_0)\ \mathsf dx_0,
\end{align}
and hence
$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty F(x_0) f(x_0)\ \mathsf dx_0 = 1 - \int_{-\infty}^\infty F(x_0) f(x_0)\ \mathsf dx_0,
$$
so that
$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty F(x_0) f(x_0)\ \mathsf dx_0 = \frac12,
$$
which completes the proof.